# Not able to boot 32bit from 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 for installation

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, 32-bit

My machine runs on 2GB RAM since the  64bit is hungry for more memory i thought of downgrading to 32bit to avoid slowness.

I downloaded 32  bit iso file and extracted the same to pendrive.
When restarted the 32bit doesn't ask for installation.

Answer (score 1):

If you extracted perfectly, then go to boot options while restarting the computer(normally pressing f12 or f9 for many computers) and select the flashdrive and install it.
If you think you didn't extract it properly, then download "iso to usb" software which makes the pendrive bootable and do the above process.